# Algorithm for Ordered Combinations

Tags: algorithm, math, mapreduce

I have the following task:

- there are 10M documents
- there are 100K unique labels
- each document has 100 labels

For each label X I need to find 10 top Y labels, where X and Y are both present in documents, ordered by the number of documents where X and Y are both present.

The task appears to be quite complex to solve:

- although the result set is only 10 records for each of 100K labels
- the straightforward algorithm of keeping all combinations as you go, is very sensitive to memory usage: there are 0.5*10^12 total combinations of (X,Y) and it grows as n^2, where n is number of labels

Is there some way I solve this without keeping all combinations in memory or break into a parallel algorithm (similar to map reduce) to solve? What if I don't need it to be 100% accurate?

Comment: Do you want to preprocess once and then serve up results for many different X, or do you have to start from scratch each time?

Comment: Well, I need to find all combinations in one go, so my result set is always Nx10, where N=100K in this example.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.  Thanks.  (Still pondering).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in the general case, you won't be able to avoid really awful runtimes - with 5050 pairs in each document, and 10M documents, all combinations seem possible.

However, in typical real-world data, you seldom have to deal with an "adversarial" input.  One potential solution is to first count the occurrences of all 100K terms, sort them, and then for each term X, do the following:

- If there are many docs with X (i.e., not less than 1% of the document count, or some other tweakable fraction), run queries against your index in the form X & Y, starting with the most popular terms and going down, keeping a heap of size 10 to track the most popular pairs.  You know that max(docs with X & Y) = max(docs with X, docs with Y), so it is very likely you will be able to short-circuit this process early
- If there are few docs with X, it is far more prudent to simply scan through all of the documents with that term and aggregate the totals yourself.

For a well-behaved document set, where the 100K terms follow a logarithmic curve with respect to document counts, you will do far less than (100)^2 * 10M work, which the naive solution would require in all cases.  Granted, for non-well-behaved document sets, you will wind up doing even more work, but that shouldn't happen in the real world.

As to "not 100% accurate", that's far too vague a specification to work with.  What kind of error is permissible?  How much of it?

--- Comment Response (too large for comment) ---

a) Think about determining the maximum of 100 million elements.  You only need to save the best 1 you have so far as you scan - the same principle applies to determining the top X of N items.  Add incoming elements to a binary heap, and remove the weakest elements when the size of the heap exceeds X.  Add the end, you will have the top X

b) Imagine you are determining the top 10 X&Y pairs, where X="Elephant".  Suppose that, after scanning 1000 Y terms, you have a heap of size 10, where the minimum-scoring pair has count 300.  Now suppose the 1001th term you check has doc count 299 - Since only 299 docs have the Y term, at most 299 docs have X&Y as well, therefore it cannot possibly be any better than any of the top 10 pairs you have so far, and since all the Y terms have been sorted by doc frequency, in fact you now know that you don't have to check any more pairs!  This is what the max statement guarantees you.

c) The choice you make for each X is purely an optimization decision.  If you have many X's that only exist in a small number of documents, that is a good problem to have - it means less work per term.

d) If you can live with some non-zero probability of the top 10 being wrong (for each term), you can probably cut way down on run-time by using a sampling method instead of a full, rigorous scan of the index.  The more prevalent a term X is in the doc index, the less documents you have to scan (proportionally) before you are likely to have the correct top 10 X&Y pairs based on the info you have gathered.  Coming up with exact numbers in this regard requires some knowledge of the expected distribution of terms in the underlying index.  In particular:  How much do terms correlate?  What does the number N(X)/MAXY(X) look like in general, where N(X) is the number of documents with the term X, and MAXY(X) is the number of documents with the pair X&Y, maximized over all terms Y != X

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer, I'm still trying to digest it. Basically the problems are around three things: a) 'keeping a heap of size 10' - how do you know that the 10 are top? b) max(X&Y) <= max(X,Y) c) 'if there are few docs with X' - what if I have many of such X's, then scanning becomes the only option? Yes, you are right that the 'not 100% accurate' is too vague, but lets assume that I can live with P probability of the top 10 being wrong (or in wrong order), 0 < P < 0.2. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the details! Still trying to figure out how this will fit my index and data structures, but your answer is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think even the worst case is not a bad you you might fear.  If there an N docs, M distnict labels but only K labels per document.  Then a complete histogram will have a hard limit K*K*N/2 distinct nonzero entries (5.5 * 10^10 with your numbers), in fact it will be far less.

BTW: I think the above point is implicit in torquestomp's answer, so you unless you are particularly interested in hard limits, you should accept his answer.